# Installing keepalived lastest version ?

Tags: software-installation

I have installed the keepalived latest [Version 1.2.16](http://www.keepalived.org/download.html) 
using

```
tar -xzvf keepalive.tar.gz
```

and

```
./configure
```

after installation I can not run it from terminal

```
sudo service keepalived start
```

or any other command it give me this

```
keepalived: unrecognized service
```

or incase of `keepalived`

```
The program 'keepalived' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:sudo apt-get install keepalived
```

how do I make it available system wide?

Thanks,

Comment: `./configure` does not make a binary. Did you run `make` after you ran configure?

Comment: i used it after you said it but still its doing the same thing

Comment: Please provide more information about what is not working. After you run `make && make install`  the binary usually goes into `/usr/local/bin/keepalived`  Is this the case?  Update your answer and add some more details of what's failing.

Comment: @val0x00ff there is nothing in `/usr/local/bin/keepalived` and i thought I have installed the keepalived using the ./configure but it doesnt work

Comment: @mchid after running sudo make install it says this in terminal https://tinyurl.com/monfhzn

Comment: @Waqas I'm not sure if you did read my first comment.  `./configure` does not create a binary. `./configure` as its name implies checks for dependencies (missing libraries, lib versions etc).  You need to follow the steps mentioned in previous comments

Comment: looks good, does it run now?

Comment: @val0x00ff i did run make after configure and it still doesnt work

Comment: @mchid No it doesnt

Comment: @Waqas  how are you running keepalived?  Does  `keepalived --help`  tell you something?

Comment: @val0x00ff yes it shows the all options but When I try to run the service using `sudo service keepalived start` it doesnt recognize the service

Comment: @mchid is there any fix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/download.html) version you like

```
tar -xzvf keepalived.gz.tar 
cd keepalived
sudo make clean
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/keepalived
```

Now, copy and paste the contents of the following into the terminal:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# keepalived   LVS cluster monitor daemon.
#
#              Written by Andres Salomon <dilinger@voxel.net>
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          keepalived
# Required-Start:    $syslog $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts keepalived
# Description:       Starts keepalived lvs loadbalancer
### END INIT INFO
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/sbin/keepalived
NAME=keepalived
DESC=keepalived
TMPFILES="/tmp/.vrrp /tmp/.healthcheckers"

#includes lsb functions 
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

test -f $CONFIG || exit 0 
test -f $DAEMON || exit 0


# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

case "$1" in
  start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    for file in $TMPFILES
    do 
            test -e $file && test ! -L $file && rm $file
    done
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid \
               --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS; then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
    fi
       ;;
  stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    if start-stop-daemon --oknodo --stop --quiet --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid \
            --exec $DAEMON; then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
    fi
       ;;
  reload|force-reload)
    log_action_begin_msg "Reloading $DESC configuration..."
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --signal 1 --pidfile \
               /var/run/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON; then
           log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_action_end_msg 1
    fi
       ;;
  restart)
    log_action_begin_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"

        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \
        /var/run/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON || true 
       sleep 1
       if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \
               /var/run/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS; then
           log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
    fi
       ;;
  *)
       echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano. Then, execute the following commands:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/keepalived
sudo /etc/init.d/keepalived start
sudo update-rc.d keepalived defaults
```

Comment: I edited the script and changed `/usr/sbin/keepalived` to  `/usr/local/sbin/keepalived`  and  included `/usr/local/sbin` and `/usr/local/bin` in the PATH

Comment: and removed `CONFIG=/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf`

Comment: but still that doesnt work like if I install the keepalived using ubuntu repository `sudo apt-get install keepalived` when I `sudo /etc/init.d/keepalived start` it doesnt show me if it has started or not

Comment: @Waqas If you did run `sudo apt-get install keepalived` you can run `sudo apt-get remove keepalived` to get rid of it. The other version you build should remain installed.

Comment: @Waqas It didn't show it had started for me also and so I edited the script posted and it works for me now. You should go ahead and run the commands again (sudo nano ...) and copy/paste what is posted now into that file and it should now output `[ ok ] Starting keepalived: keepalived.` when you start the service. Don't forget to update-rc.d!

Comment: Well, It worked on one machine but it doesnt work other I have done the same thing but still no luck

Comment: @Waqas You can run `whereis keepalived` to see if it is installed correctly. It should say `/usr/local/sbin/keepalived`. If not, you may need to cd into the  keepalive-1.2.16 directory, run `sudo make clean` before you run `./configure` then `make` and `sudo make install` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23727/discussion-between-waqas-and-mchid).

Answer (score 3):

## Read the manual!

The *`keepalived` User Guide* has had instructions for doing this since 2001.  **Follow them.**  The *User Guide* is considered out of date, but in fact only part 2 of the instructions are outdated.  Part 1 (`./configure && make && make install` as the superuser) is still valid.

Part 2 is outdated because it addresses an old System 5 `rc` way of creating a `keepalived` dæmon service, and that for Fedora-style System 5 `rc` no less.  You're using Ubuntu Linux.  You've had upstart for years and you have systemd nowadays.

## systemd

For systemd, write your own local *service unit* and place it (because it is a non-system non-packaged local-administrator unit) in `/etc/systemd/system/keepalived.service`.  Here's one of mine, incorporating two bugfixes:

```
#
# keepalived control files for systemd
#
# Incorporates fixes from RedHat bug #769726.

[Unit]
Description=LVS and VRRP High Availability monitor
After=network.target
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

[Service]
Type=simple
# Ubuntu/Debian convention:
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/keepalived
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/keepalived --dont-fork
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
# keepalived needs to be in charge of killing its own children.
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You'll have to adjust this unit for the fact that you've installed into `/usr/local` rather than `/usr`.  After that, the *normal systemd controls apply*:

- `systemctl preset keepalived.service` to have the service automatically start at bootstrap.
- `systemctl start keepalived.service` to start the service manually.
- `systemctl status keepalived.service` to view the service status.

And so forth.

## upstart

Your package hasn't come with an upstart *job file*.  Having never had need of `keepalived` under upstart myself, this is just a skeleton `/etc/init/keepalived.conf` that you will have to work on.

```
description "LVS and VRRP High Availability monitor"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

exec /usr/sbin/keepalived --dont-fork
```

## Further reading

- Alexandre Cassen (2001). "INSTALLING KEEPALIVED". [*`keepalived` User Guide*](http://keepalived.org/pdf/UserGuide.pdf).  keepalived.org.  p. 8.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200281/5132